# How do I fix a "Expected Primary-expression before ')' token" error?

Tags: c++, token

Here is my code. I keep getting this error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

```
void showInventory(player& obj) {   // By Johnny :D
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    std::cout << "\nINVENTORY:\n" + obj.getItem(i);
    i++;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t" + obj.getItem(i) + "\n";
    i++;
}
}

std::string toDo() //BY KEATON
{
std::string commands[5] =   // This is the valid list of commands.
    {"help", "inv"};

std::string ans;
std::cout << "\nWhat do you wish to do?\n>> ";
std::cin >> ans;

if(ans == commands[0]) {
    helpMenu();
    return NULL;
}
else if(ans == commands[1]) {
    showInventory(player);     // I get the error here.
    return NULL;
}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`showInventory(player);` is passing a type as parameter. That's illegal, you need to pass an object.

For example, something like:

```
player p;
showInventory(p);
```

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
int main()
{
   player player;
   toDo();
}
```

which is awful. First, don't name the object the same as your type. Second, in order for the object to be visible inside the function, you'll need to pass it as parameter:

```
int main()
{
   player p;
   toDo(p);
}
```

and

```
std::string toDo(player& p) 
{
    //....
    showInventory(p);
    //....
}
```

Comment: 'player' is the object name though. I am trying to pass the object 'player'.

Comment: @user1743924 really? Where is it declared (certainly not in the code you posted)? In fact, the line `showInventory(player& obj)` tells us that `player` is a type, not an object.

Comment: @user1743924 you named a variable the same as the type? **Don't**. Regardless, that variable is declared in `main`, not in `toDo`. You'll need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    player player;`

Answer (score 1):

```
showInventory(player);     // I get the error here.

void showInventory(player& obj) {   // By Johnny :D
```

this means that player is an datatype and showInventory expect an referance to an variable of type player.

so the correct code will be

```
  void showInventory(player& obj) {   // By Johnny :D
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << "\nINVENTORY:\n" + obj.getItem(i);
        i++;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t" + obj.getItem(i) + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    }

players myPlayers[10];

    std::string toDo() //BY KEATON
    {
    std::string commands[5] =   // This is the valid list of commands.
        {"help", "inv"};

    std::string ans;
    std::cout << "\nWhat do you wish to do?\n>> ";
    std::cin >> ans;

    if(ans == commands[0]) {
        helpMenu();
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(ans == commands[1]) {
        showInventory(myPlayers[0]);     // or any other index,also is not necessary to have an array
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: The correct way is certainly not having globals. The correct way is passing the object as a parameter.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but when you have global function in C style,  having global object is not so bad.

Comment: Having anything C-style in C++ code is not bad, right... it's awful.

Comment: Why not globals? In a game, wouldn't you want to program the player as a global?

Comment: Not really this is why in C++ we have class. You can have a PlayersManager with getter/setter or something like this to handle players.

Comment: Think about variables lifetime and you will get the answer about when to not use global variables and why is better to use objects managed by other objects

Comment: I have a lot of global functions in header files and I included them all. Should I do something different? Like put them in a class so that I don't have the not in namespace errors?

Comment: One of the main idea of OOP is encapsulation from this POV at list from POV of maintenance the life will be easier.